# Ошибка "Not enough arguments for format string"

Tags: mysql, django

Всем привет! Странное поведение в первом варианте отрабатывает как надо, а во втором ошибку выдает "not enough arguments for format string", кто может пояснить?

1) Первый вариант

```
import MySQLdb
base = MySQLdb.connect(host="1.1.1.1",user="111",passwd="111",db="111")
cursor = base.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT login, full_name, actual_address FROM users WHERE login LIKE '%{0}%' AND is_deleted=0;".format('111'))
res = cursor.fetchall()
return render(request, 'search/search.html', {'forms': SearchForm(), 'res': res})
```

2) Второй вариант

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT login, full_name, actual_address FROM users WHERE login LIKE '%{0}%' AND is_deleted=0;".format('111'))
res = cursor.fetchall()
return render(request, 'search/search.html', {'forms': SearchForm(), 'res': res})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуй экранировать %, поставив их два раза, а то он ждет на каждый %, что ты передаешь переменную.

```
SELECT login, full_name, actual_address FROM users WHERE login LIKE '%%{0}%%' AND is_deleted=0
```